# How do cycles' emission strength values relate to real-world units?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

If I wanted to accurately reproduce the brightness of a real-world object in Cycles to see how Cycles rendered it, how would I convert the real-world units (like lux) into strength values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation: "Strength input: Strength of the emitted light. For point and area lamps, the unit is Watts. For materials, a value of 1.0 will ensure that the object in the image has the exact same color as the Color input, i.e. make it ‘shadeless’."

Comment: ...but I'd still like to know if there's a good way to measure this for materials.

Comment: Watts is a real world unit of measurement. Maybe you want something like a [lux to watts conversion](http://www.rapidtables.com/calc/light/lux-to-watt-calculator.htm)?

Comment: Yes, watt is a real-world unit, but this value for watts doesn't apply to materials, only to lamps.

Comment: Emission materials use watts per square meter.

Comment: Cool! Do you have a source for that?